# Set background color in java Graphics object

Tags: java, graphics, colors, background, border

Good day,

Know that in Java Graphics object, we can user the `setColor()` method to set the object color. But this is only apply to the object border. Is it anyway to set color for the whole object? I means the background of the Graphics object.

```
void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRect(left, right, width, height);

    }
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `fillRect()` method .

```
 g.fillRect(left, right, width, height);
```

from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

---

`drawRect()`

> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics context's current color.

`fillRect()`

> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current 
>   color.

---

" *this is only apply to the object border* " because `drawRect` draw the outlines only.
" *Is it anyway to set color for the whole object?* " well you misunderstand . and `setColor()` set the color to what you draw if you draw a outline then you can see outline only and it's not because of <strike>`setColor()` set colors to border</strike> .